# KeyboardButton Telegram Api выполняет нажатие на ссылкy

Tags: php, java, telegram-bot, telegram

В чате телеграма при нажате на номер телефона полученный в сообщение всплывает окошко с предложение звонить на номер или нет.
Можно ли с помощью KeyboardButton при нажатие на кнопке всплывало такое окошко?

Answer (score 1):

**Нет**. Ни *Telegram API*, ни *Bot API* не предоставляют такой возможности. Ознакомьтесь с документацией:

1. [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/methods)
2. [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)